# Is there a way of setting the UIBlurEffect black and white in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I have a `view` called `componentsView` that overlays `mkmapview`. I thought it would be cool to have this view transparent with a blur effect. So in my `viewDidLoad` method I typed:

```
let blur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blur)
blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
blurView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth, .FlexibleHeight]
componentsView.insertSubview(blurView, atIndex: 0)
```

and that works, it blurs the map behind it. But the map is still colorful - is there a way of making it black and white? currently my panel has a clear color and I tried setting its tint color to black but that didn't work...

Comment: did you find the solution??

Comment: hm I think I did not, I used the png file instead... But if there's anything that comes to your mind - feel free to write it below ;)